# If each record has an open and close date, how to display active records over time

Tags: cognos

If each record has an open and close date, how I can to display number of active records on last day of each quarter.
I am using IBM Cognos Analytics 11.0.9 and I am relatively new... Please Just a hint were to go... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Close Date data item is null or a specific dummy value when the item is active, you can simply count rows where that condition is met.

```
TOTAL(
    CASE 
    WHEN [Active Date] <= current_date AND [Close Date] is null 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END 
for report)
```

If you need to aggregate the count for something other the entire report, change the 'for' clause to list out the data items you want to roll the count up to.

For example, to roll the count up to a data item named [Item]:

```
TOTAL(
...
...
...
for [Item])
```